# Nginx SSL for Docker Apps

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I've looked through a few different posts, but can't seem to find the adequate config for NGINX to SSL a port, hosting a docker app (e.g. portainer, or homeassist)

As of right now I have it working so that https://internal.example.com is currently enabled with SSL for an arbitrary index.html space.

I have portainer mapped in my router from `5100:9000` and if I access `http://internal.example.com:5100`, I can get to my portainer.

However, when trying https://internal.example.com:5100 the result is: `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name internal.example.com;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    #for certbot challenges (renewal process)
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /data/letsencrypt;
    }
}

#https://internal.example.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name internal.example.com;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/internal.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/internal.example.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/internal.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/internal.example.com/privkey.pem;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html

    return 301 https://internal.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

What am I missing to have that configuration file address a) 1 port of a docker port or b) any future docker ports.

**Update: 2018-08-20**
I've added the server block:

```
server {
  listen 8223 ssl;
  server_name int.example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/int.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/int.example.com/privkey.pem;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

location /{
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.199:8123/;
        #proxy_redirect http://192.168.1.199:8123/ $scheme://$host:9443;
    }
}
```

However, its almost as if it's not even listening on the port, because it simply times out.

Answer (score 1):

You are needed another server config in your nginx which will setup ssl on a port 5100. See [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/828135) for details

Comment: I attempted a similar config, do I just then remove this portion? `root /var/www/myexample.com; index index.html index.htm;` Because I have no index to refer to, it's the contents of the docker container.

Comment: you may need to replace that with what it should be for your specific case

Comment: Right, but if it's a docker container I don't necessarily have an index.html, so does that go to the container file? How would I get it to just retrieve what natively pulls from http://int.example.com:5100

Comment: if your app is static - package you container image with those static files, if the app is dynamic - proxy the request to the further systems. Basically, it is the same as you would do without docker